# Blender 2.93 does not save view layer render setting after selecting a different view layer

Tags: rendering, collections, viewlayers

Using Blender 2.93.3. Cycles, though I don't think that has anything to do with this. My scene consists of nine collections and eight view layers for compositing. After I enable rendering for a particular set of collections in a view layer via the "renders" check boxes in the outliner, the render selections are not saved after I move on to the next view layer and enable rendering for that layer's set of collections to be rendered. When I return to the original view layer, it has acquired the render settings for the view layer I just set up and lost the render settings that are appropriate for it.

It's as if the outliner has lost its ability to save render selections after switching between view layers. Whatever the render setting was for the last view layer set up is the render setting for all view layers. This is frustrating and I've attempted every way I cant think of to fix the issue.

My scene shows that there are seven users though I can't click the "7" to make a single user copy. Every time I do that it just creates a new scene. I made single user copies out of all of the collections.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use different render setting for different view layers because is the same scene file; instead of view layers, if you make different scenes, you can use different render settings.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Emir. I guess I'm confused. Does this mean that in a particular scene, I cannot vary which view layers are rendered between view layers? Does it mean that if I want to render some view layers and not others, I have to create a new scene for each different iteration of view layers I want to render?

Comment: If you want to render some view layers but not others, you could go to View layer properties > User view layer for rendering. And you can do this to every single layer.